# MySQL, Confused w/ query / Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function.

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I have 3 tables.

```
  Video (Id, ViewCount, Location)
  Likes (Id, Video, User)
  Location (Id, Name)
```

How would I query the four highest ranked videos (sum of Video.ViewCount + count(Likes.User)
  Group them by Video.Id, and return the top 4 results from a specific location.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT  Video.Id, sum(Video.ViewCount + count(Likes.User)) as Points From Video
  Left Join Likes
  ON Likes.Video=Video.Id
  WHERE Video.Location=30
  GROUP BY Video.Id
  ORDER BY Points DESC
  LIMIT 4;
```

But I get an invalid use of group function. Does anybody have any pointers ??

Comment: You cannot use aggregation functions within other aggregation functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  id,
        viewcount +
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    likes l
        WHERE   l.video = v.id
        ) AS points
FROM    video v
WHERE   location = 30
ORDER BY
        points DESC, id
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: just had to add a v to the end of FROM video and it worked like a charm. Thank for steering me in the right direction.